# How to sort by biggest ID to smallest in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table which has the classical `id` column.

So far I have this query: `select company, url from clients order by id;`, but the result table is sorted from smallest id to biggest.

I want to force the query to return results sorted decreasingly.

Comment: try adding the direction indicator 'desc' in your order by -- 'order by id desc'.  'asc' for ascending and 'desc' for descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [**`desc`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-order.html) keyword.

`select company, url from clients order by id desc;`

Answer (score 2):

Use `ASC` or `DESC` after each `ORDER BY` column.

```
SELECT company, url 
FROM clients 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Or with multiple columns:

```
SELECT company, url 
FROM clients 
ORDER BY company ASC, url DESC;
```

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-order-by/